# Вывод метода объекта имя которого заданное в переменной

Tags: javascript, json, ооп, объекты

Как вывести с объекта `foo` тот метод, который задан в переменной `obl`?

```
var foo = {
   pr: "aaa",
   wr: "bbb",
   bg: "ccc"
};

var obl = 'pr';

document.write(foo.obl);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется [Bracket Notation(Скобочная нотация)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
document.write(foo[obl]);
```